# My android studio cant download the emulator please helpout

Tags: android, flutter, error-handling, editor, development-environment

Packages to install: - Android Emulator (emulator)

Preparing "Install Android Emulator (revision: 31.2.10)".
Failed to read or create install properties file.
Failed packages:

- Android Emulator (emulator)

Answer (score 2):

try running Android studio as administrator, sometimes using VPN can help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be related to some reasons:

1. Android Studio version: Try to download latest android studio version, because the emulator version you want to download is the latest release.
2. If the first options doesn't work, problem can be  related to the emulator version. As I said, it is the latest version, bugs can be inevitable, if it is not important, try to download some old version.
3. Maybe your internet connection is not stable.

I hope it helped you, good luck!